# Ajax call to php function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to post to MySQL with jQuery and PHP:

jQuery:

```
var data = $("#prueba").text();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "insertar_mysql.php",
  data: {
    values: data
  },
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg) {
      alert('success'); //testing purposes
    } else {
      alert('fail'); //testing purposes
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the same folder I have the file `insert_mysql.php`, and the code is

```
$nombre = $_POST['values'];
```

The problem is that the AJAX function does not work, and don't know exactly why. The code never goes into `insertar_mysql.php`.

***UPDATE:***

i solved the problem, the file directory was wrong, but actually i have on more problem, chorme console says:

```
    POST http://uplaber.com/manager/insertar_mysql.php 403 (Forbidden) jquery-latest.js:8706
    send jquery-latest.js:8706
    x.extend.ajax jquery-latest.js:8136
(anonymous function) uplaber-manager:988
x.event.dispatch jquery-latest.js:5095
v.handle
```

any advice , why is forbidden??

Comment: are you sure that file name is insertar_mysql.php or insert_mysql.php ?

Comment: Use `alert(data);` befor ajax.See firefox console and check errors.

Comment: do you return a msg? because if you don't return a msg from `insertar_mysql.php` the ajax function will always return the alert fail..

Comment: yes is insertar_mysql.php, the file name is correct, I will correct it in the post, thanks!

Comment: @yonessafari yes, i do and data is correct

Comment: you probably have an error in your php file. that's why ajax success callback doesn't fire. create a `test.php` file with content `<?php print_r($_POST); %>`. if it works then you can start to debug your `insertar_mysql.php`

Comment: What is the exact address of the file(**insertar_mysql.php**)?

Comment: the hint @NiyaziMakuloglu gave was the best so far. Check the network tab of your browser inspector. You get all the results (e.g. header, response, etc.) of your request there.

Comment: @NiyaziMakuloglu the weird thing is that insertar_mysql.php , works perfectly if i execute manually and I put $nombre = "anything",but when i call from ajax didn't work , so i think insertar_myswl.php code is good

Comment: @yonessafari all the code is locate in a ftp file, insertar_mysql.php is in the same directory as the file where i call the ajax function

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat   i have an error in the browser console, file not found .. thanks for the answer i will try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ajax function with following in this function i have added error event to make sure that is there any error in your ajax call.

```
var data = $("#prueba").text();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "insertar_mysql.php",
  data: {
    values: data
  },
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg) {
      alert('success'); //testing purposes
    } else {
      alert('fail'); //testing purposes
    }
  },
  error:function(e){
      alert("something wrong"+ e) // this will alert an error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $("#prueba").text();
var dataString = "value="+data;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "insertar_mysql.php",
  data: dataString ,
  success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg); //testing purposes
  }
});
```

PHP

```
$nombre = $_POST['value'];
echo $nombre;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `insertar_mysql.php` in the like address:
`[drive]:\wamp\www\insertar_mysql.php`,You use `url: "/insertar_mysql.php"` else like `[drive]:\wamp\www\new\insertar_mysql.php`,You use `url: "/new/insertar_mysql.php"` 
Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"insertar_mysql.php",
    data:{values: data},
    dataType:"html",
    cache:false,
    context:document.body,
    type:"POST",
    success: function(result) {
        if (msg) {
            alert('success'); //testing purposes
        } else {
            alert('fail'); //testing purposes
        }
    },Error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in chrome console this

```
POST http://uplaber.com/index.php/es/insertar_mysql.php 404 (Not Found) jquery-  latest.js:8706
send jquery-latest.js:8706
x.extend.ajax jquery-latest.js:8136
(anonymous function) uplaber-manager:988
x.event.dispatch jquery-latest.js:5095
v.handle jquery-latest.js:4766
```

so i think my problem is the directory of my insertar_mysql-php file is not correct, i will try to find the exact directory.

Comment: OMG the problem is, in eclipse the directory that aparently is my file, is not correct, i checked the directory with filezilla and now WORKS!!!!!!!!